# SQL Server DATEDIFF keeps ignoring seconds part of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am getting `0` on executing the following statement:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:01') * CONVERT(BIGINT,60)*1000  as BidTicks
```

Whereas I get `6000` on executing this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:01:01') * CONVERT(BIGINT,60)*1000  as BidTicks
```

What are my options?

Comment: `mi` is for minute ;).

Comment: @shA.t I was under the impression that it is for miliseconds.

Comment: This is why you should always write the full `DATEPART` in your query e.g. `MINUTE`, `MILLISECOND` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use s or ss for your  expected output .

```
select DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:01') * CONVERT(BIGINT,60)*1000  as BidTicks
```

it will prodece :

```
60000
```

Answer (score 1):

To return the difference in seconds as the first argument in your query, you'll want to use seconds as the argument, which is an s:

```
select DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:01:01')
```

Basically, your query is asking for the number of minutes between the two. Your first query returns 0, the second returns 1.

Therefore `0 * 60 * 1000 = 0` and `1 * 60 * 1000 = 60000`

Try the following:

```
select DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:01:01') 
-- * convert(BIGINT,60) wasn't sure if this was necessary still
* 1000  as BidTicks
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `s` or `ss` instead of `mi`

```
select DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00','1970-01-01 00:00:01') * CONVERT(BIGINT,60)*1000  as BidTicks
```

---

```
datepart    | Abbreviations  
------------+---------------
hour        | hh 
minute      | mi, n 
second      | ss, s 
millisecond | ms 
microsecond | mcs
nanosecond  | ns
```